# x86-64 storing and removing floating point values from the stack segfaults

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, stack, sse

So I thought that I should make simple helper functions for moving data between stack and `XMM` registers but I'm again segfaulting. How should this be done properly? Below is my current code that segfaults:

```
pushxmm0:
    SUB RSP, 8;Move the stack
    MOVSD QWORD [RSP], XMM0
    RET

popxmm0:
    MOVSD XMM0, QWORD [RSP]
    ADD RSP, 8;Move the stack
    RET

main:
    ;Do stuff here
    CALL pushxmm0
    ;Do more stuff
    CALL popxmm0 ;Restore the register value (segfault)
```

EDIT: does this have something to do with the calling of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before executing the first instruction of `pushxmm0` routine, the stack looks like this:

```
... used stack ...
RA      # return address in main, pointing to "CALL popxmm0"
        <--- RSP points here
... unused stack ...
```

Now we execute the `SUB` and `MOVSD` instructions. The stack now looks like this:

```
... used stack ...
RA
copy of XMM0
              <--- RSP points here
... unused stack ...
```

Question: where will the (next) `RET` instruction return?

It should be pretty clear that it will not return to the intended (RA) address.

Comment: Oh yeah, so I would have to move the `RSP` to point to the proper return address, indeed this seems to be the problem here but this also clobbers the stack and the routine does not perform as expected as after the return the RSP points to "wrong" address, will implement this with macros instead.

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer : Are you writing some reverse polish notation calculator?